# Regex matching multiple delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split on the following delimiters: full stop, semi-colon, *, +, ? and - 
However, I want to only split on the '-' when it occurs at the beginning of a sentence (so as to not split words like "non-functional"

I tried the following but I am not making any progress, any help will be appreciated:

```
sentences = re.split("[.-;]*[\+]*[\?]*[\*]*", txt)
```

here is the sample text I've been trying this on:

```
- Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools
* Updated Dropbox support 
* Improved
stability
- New icon                                                                          
* See this case mis-alignment
```

Expected output after the split is a list of items:

```
TextEditor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools, Updated Dropbox support, Improved stability, New icon, See this case mis-alignment
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by that you are "not making any progress"? Can you post what the exact problem is?

Comment: Is there a reason you are splitting your delimiters into different character sets `[...]` ?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `re.split` function.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''- Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools
* Updated Dropbox support 
* Improved
stability
- New icon'''
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'(?m)\s*^[-*+?]+\s*', s) if i]
['Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools', 'Updated Dropbox support', 'Improved\nstability', 'New icon']
```

Comment: thanks Avinash...I noticed you used the multi-line, how would I go about splitting if there is a full-stop at the end of a line, since multi-line is enabled.

Comment: try `[i for i in re.split(r'(?m)\s*^[-*+?]+\s*|\.$', s) if i]`

Answer (score 1):

Try enumerating your delimiters like this:

> re.split("[.;*+?] ")

Answer (score 1):

if you want to split your string in a defined set of delimiters than do it this way:

```
>>> txt = '- Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools'
>>> r = re.split(r'([.;*+?-]+)',txt)
>>> r
['', '-', ' Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools']
```

If you don't want to get in the resulting list those delimiters than:

```
>>> r = re.split(r'[.;*+?-]+',txt)
>>> r
['', ' Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools']
```

EDIT: in response to your below comment, use `\s` for spaces:

```
    >>> txt = '''- Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools
    * Updated Dropbox support 
    * Improved
    stability
    - New icon'''
     >>> r = re.split('(^|\s)+[.;*+?-]+($|\s)+',txt) 
     >>> [i for i in r if len(i) > 1]
['Text Editor: Now you can edit plain text files with airport tools', 'Updated Dropbox support', 'Improved\n    stability', 'New icon']
```

Comment: thanks, that works just about perfectly, except that the sentence splits on "-" where I don't want it to split e..g in words like "re-written". More generally, I want to split on "-" if it occurs at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @newdev14 .. is that the same if it is at the middle and end of your string?

Comment: if there's a '-' anywhere but the beginning of a sentence, I don't want to split....does that make sense?

Comment: @newdev14 .. check my updated answer...let me know if it needs more improvement, as I'm not sure only splitting over those delimiter will give you your expected output...we need to work on that more